# XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/myapp/jsonurl/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

`$.ajax()` request from html page in django project,it work with firefox but not working with chrome .i tried many things from google but not getting any result ,i waste my 2 day plz help 
Error on chrome console :

XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://example.com/myapp/jsonurl/.` No `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

My code :

```
ajax code:
 $.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/myapp/jsonurl/",
    dataType:"json",
    type:"GET",
    success: function(data){
      alert(data);
    },
    error: function(xhRequest, ErrorText, thrownError){
      alert(xhRequest+ ErrorText+thrownError);
    }
  });
```

url:

```
url(r'^jsonurl/', planViews.jsonurl,name='jsonurl'),
```

view:

```
def jsonurltest(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps("{'jsondata':'ajax test'}"), content_type="application/json")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got solution there are two problem in my project

1:install https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers

2: i used "@login_required" with my view when remove this work properly with chrom all browser

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

Make sure you use the same name (www.example.com in both for example)

Or if you have to keep two different name, make sure the server serving the AJAX call add a header:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com>

More info about can be found on:
http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2013/09/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-request.html

Comment: thanx for replay ,what do u mean "same name" ,i only grant  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*" in server at httpd.conf file

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/myapp/jsonurl/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.` that show both "example dot com" and "www dot example dot com" which are different. are you sure your Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is sent correctly? have you look at the http reply?